# Android Web Driver - cannot simulate touch actions

Tags: android, selenium, web, driver, ui-automation

I've downloaded the android_webdriver_library.jar via the Eclipse ADT SDK Manager under Extras/Google Web Driver and reference it in my eclipse project.

How do I simulate a touch action like tapping a button for example? I cannot find the TouchActions class which according to the documentation (http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/index.html) is supposed to be the factory class for touch actions.

Answer (score 0):

i don't know Java, but I got this working in Python.
What does your code look like? Can you try the [Tutorial](http://google-opensource.blogspot.com/2011/10/test-your-mobile-web-apps-with.html)  , as well as the example below and modify it to use touch?

Example from tutorial below:

```
WebElement toFlick = driver.findElement(By.id("image"));
// 400 pixels left at normal speed
Action flick = getBuilder(driver).flick(toFlick, 0, -400, FlickAction.SPEED_NORMAL)
        .build();
flick.perform();
WebElement secondImage = driver.findElement(“secondImage”);
assertTrue(secondImage.isDisplayed());
```